# Including dependencies with ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying out ember-cli to get an ember project going, however I have previously relied on rails and the asset pipeline to compile all my js and (s)css for previous projects.

I admit a weak understanding of js build tools, so apologies if the question is basic: How can I see what dependencies are being compiled/included in the build?  Specifically, I want to include both zurb-foundation and ember-leaflet in my project. I am not sure if they are there (at least the leaflet map is not showing up in the project --- using a basic example that worked with both rails and rail-eak).

The files (ember-leaflet, etc) are in the vendor directory of the project and were placed there thru *bower install* (I assume?); do I have to manually include them in the root bower.json file (currently they  are not); is the order in bower.json important?

Thanks in advance.

DJ

Comment: If the dependencies are already in the vendor directory, just add the js files to 'legacyFilesToAppend' in the Brocfile.js. This should give you an idea https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/234

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some digging and a lot of reading I found the solution [here](http://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/803/files#r13024213) and got ember-leaflet to work.

1.) Download the libs

```
bower install --save leaflet
bower install --save ember-leaflet
```

Note: It's probably not neccessary to download leaflet, since ember-leaflet seems to have it included (leaflet-dist).This is the part I did manually a few times, so you may or may not have vendor/leaflet-dist. Just change accordingly.

2.) Configure building the assets

Add the import lines in your **Brocfile.js** before the module.exports line

```
app.import('vendor/leaflet-dist/leaflet-src.js')
app.import('vendor/leaflet-dist/leaflet.css')
app.import('vendor/ember-leaflet/dist/ember-leaflet.js')

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

3) make Leaflet and EmberLeaflet known to Ember (**.jshintrc**)

```
{
  "predef": {
    ...
    "L": true,
    "EmberLeaflet": true
  }
  ...
}
```

4) create a view

```
export default EmberLeaflet.MapView.extend({
  classNames : ['ember-leaflet-map']
});
```

5) create a template using the view (where view name corresponds to the file name, here *views/mapview.js*)

```
<div id="map">
  {{view 'mapview'}}
</div>
```

6) check / add vendor style sheet to app/index.html (should be present with recent versions of ember-cli)

```
<head>
   ...
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor.css">
</head>
```

7) run Ember

```
ember server
```

8) Bonus: In case you are using **Twitter Bootstrap 3** here's the css I had to add to app/styles/app.css (could probably be simplified)

```
html,
body {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
.page-content {
  padding: 40px 15px;
  height: 100%;
}
.row {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
.ember-leaflet-map {
  height: 100%;
}
body > .ember-view {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks for posting this information; this solution has come to light over the last week or so. I fumbled my way to almost the identical solution, reading the referenced doc PR from ember-cli.  I think the only difference was I did not link the the stylesheet in the <head>, since I was using scss so I @import and had to copy to leaflet images to the /public/images folder....thanks again.

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution. I just banged my head on the wall the last 5 days about Ember-Leaflet integration. I hope there won't be any from-outer-space tricks to control this map with Ember controllers !

Answer (score 1):

It seems like somebody just created an ember-cli addon: https://www.npmjs.org/package/ember-cli-ember-leaflet

I'm going to try it :)

Comment: Nice. I tried to create a small app using ember-cli (0.0.39-master-1b6fcf0cad) with ember-cli-ember-leaflet but could not get it to work. I needed to add the ember-cli-leaflet dependency (and move it above ember-leaflet in the package.json file, as instructed on the [ember-cli-ember-leaflet](http://github.com/csantero/ember-cli-ember-leaflet) github instructions. I also had to add broccoli-static-assets and broccoli-merge-trees. However, the console error is the L is undefined. How did you import ember-leaflet into your view?

Comment: hm, the addon has changed since I installed it. I had also to install broccoli-static-assets and broccoli-merge-trees. Then I just used in my view class something like export default EmberLeaflet.MapView.extend({...}). I will try to update to the last 0.0.6 and see how it could work.

Comment: Okay. I figured this one out, and here is the recap. Follow the instructions for [ember-cli-ember-leaflet](https://github.com/csantero/ember-cli-ember-leaflet).Add broccoli-static-assets and broccoli-merge-trees.  In your view, you should import the following: import EmberLeaflet from 'ember-leaflet';
import L from 'L';  and finally you have to hack the ember-leaflet and leaflet vendor files as suggested in [this](https://github.com/csantero/ember-cli-ember-leaflet/issues/1) issue. Phewww.