# Ember CLI: ENOENT, no such file or directory ember-data.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, npm, bower, ember-cli

I have a new ember-cli app and I'm trying to create a version of TodoMVC with ember-cli version 0.0.32.

In my models/todo.js file I have:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Todo = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean')
});

export default Todo;
```

but when I run `ember server` I get this error:

```
version: 0.0.32
Livereload server on port 35729
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:4200
ENOENT, no such file or directory '/<my_path>/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-OWIN6XGL.tmp/ember-data.js'
```

I've tried:

- `npm cache clear`
- `npm install`
- `bower install`

But didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out because this [barely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461712/including-dependencies-with-ember-cli) mentioned the 'brocfile.js' file and so I compared my 'brocfile.js' file with the '[brocfile.js](https://github.com/WMeldon/ember-cli-todos/blob/1b337a14eaef9bc8787081b5884fdda7abd4a216/Brocfile.js)' file in an example [ember-cli TodoMVC app](https://github.com/WMeldon/ember-cli-todos) and noticed one small difference:

```
app.import({
  development: 'vendor/ember-data/ember-data.js',
  production:  'vendor/ember-data/ember-data.prod.js'
+}, {
 +  'ember-data': [
 +    'default'
 +  ]
});
```

The `+`'s are the [changes](https://github.com/WMeldon/ember-cli-todos/commit/1b337a14eaef9bc8787081b5884fdda7abd4a216#diff-ec6fb87583b2323d013c3e30c0a5084d) that need to be made to the 'brocfile.js' file in order to get ember-data to work.

Now run `ember server` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that [ember-cli TodoMVC app](https://github.com/WMeldon/ember-cli-todos) doesn't need those lines anymore, and the default ember-cli app doesn't have them either.

I had a similar error to yours, saying "no such file or directory: ....\ember-dat.js" and it turns out that I just hadn't done `import DS from 'ember-data'` in app/adapters/application.js.